# Jquery or JavaScript || Multiplying & dividing two dynamic input fields with eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a calculation form where there are two input value's: regular numbers and percentages.

I want the input value with the regular numbers to be divided by the input value with the percentages.

Example:

*(you have value 1 which is a regular number)*

Value 1: 60

*(you have value 2 which is a regular percentage)*

value 2: 20%

these two values should be divided by each other in the following manner

60 *(value 1)* * 20% *(value 2)* = *(result)* 12

I understand that the code to achieve this would look like the following:

```
    var value1 = $('#input1').val();
    var value2 = $('#input2').val();
    var result = $('#result');

    result.val(value1/100 * value2);
```

But here comes the tricky part.

The input fields are **dynamic** meaning the user could create 20 input fields for both the regular numbers as the percentages, if he/she would desire to do this.

This means that the code written above isn't enough anymore and I need to write a code that dynamically runs to all input fields to calculate it all.

i'm creating  this app in "*Ruby on Rails 5*".

I've used Nested fields & Jquery to dynamically add new input fields and remove them.

Now i've written this code:

```
  $(".domestic-object-procentages-low").each(function(i) {
      $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-procentages-low-1-" + (i + 1));
  });
```

The purpose of this code is to give each created and current domestic-object an unique id by adding +1 *(value 1)*

Now I've written another code:

```
      $(".domestic-object-procentages-2-low").each(function(i) {
      $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-procentages-low-1-2-" + (i + 1));
  });
```

which pretty much does the same with an two added to it. *(value 2)*

Now what i'm trying to do is to divide the the value of the first input field by a 100 and multiply it with the value of a third input field.

The result of this should be stored in the second field.

This is what I've managed to get so far

```
  var i=0;
  $("#domestic-input-2-low-" + (i + 1)).each(function(i) {
    $(this).val()= $("#value3-0").val()/100 * $("#domestic-input-low-" + (i + 1)).each.val()
  })
```

I am now running into a problem where my coding skills aren't enough to solve my current problem.

And i'm asking the community of stack overflow, how I can best tackle this problem and achieve what i'm trying to do.

I hope I've explained it all well enough for you too understand.

Thank you kindly

**HTML FILE**

**INPUT 1**

```
<div class="field">
      <h1>Objectives</h1>

          <h4>Domestic</h4>
     <% if @managment.objectives.any? %>
      <% @managment.objectives.each do |object| %>

        <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="objectiveinput" onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.objectivesname1 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object-procentages-low" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.lowprocent1 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object-procentages-med" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.medprocent1 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object-procentages-high" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.highprocent1 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object-low" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.lowobjectives1 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object-med" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.medobjectives1 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object-high" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.highobjectives1 %>">

      <br>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <h4>continental</h4>
     <% if @managment.continentals.any? %>
      <% @managment.continentals.each do |continental| %>

        <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="objectiveinput" onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.objectivesname2 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object-procentages-low" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.lowprocent2 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object-procentages-med" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.medprocent2 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object-procentages-high" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.highprocent2 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object-low" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.lowobjectives2 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object-med" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.medobjectives2 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object-high" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.highobjectives2 %>">
   <br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<h4>International</h4>
 <% if @managment.internationals.any? %>
  <% @managment.internationals.each do |international| %>

    <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="objectiveinput" onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.objectivesname3 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object-procentages-low" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.lowprocent3 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object-procentages-med" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.medprocent3 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object-procentages-high" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.highprocent3 %>">%
    <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object-low" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.lowobjectives3 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object-med" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.medobjectives3 %>">
    <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object-high" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.highobjectives3 %>">

  <br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**INPUT 2**

```
        <div class="field">
      <h1>Objectives</h1>

    <h4>Domestic</h4>
     <% if @managment.objectives.any? %>
      <% @managment.objectives.each do |object| %>

        <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="objectiveinput" onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.objectivesname1 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object-procentages-2-low" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.lowprocent1 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object-procentages-2-med" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.medprocent1 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object-procentages-2-high" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.highprocent1 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object2-low" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.lowobjectives1 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object2-med" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.medobjectives1 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object2-high" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.highobjectives1 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object2" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.highobjectives1 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object2" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.highobjectives1 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages domestic-object2" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= object.highobjectives1 %>">
      <br>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <h4>continental</h4>
     <% if @managment.continentals.any? %>
      <% @managment.continentals.each do |continental| %>

        <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="objectiveinput" onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.objectivesname2 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object-procentages-2-low" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.lowprocent2 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object-procentages-2-med" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.medprocent2 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object-procentages-2-high" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.highprocent2 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object2-low" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.lowobjectives2 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object2-med" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.medobjectives2 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object2-high" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.highobjectives2 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object2" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.highobjectives2 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object2" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.highobjectives2 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages continental-object2" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= continental.highobjectives2 %>">
       <br>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <h4>International</h4>
     <% if @managment.internationals.any? %>
      <% @managment.internationals.each do |international| %>

        <input class="inputbudget procentages" id="objectiveinput" onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.objectivesname3 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object-procentages-2-low" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.lowprocent3 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object-procentages-2-med" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.medprocent3 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object-procentages-2-high" id="procentages"  onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.highprocent3 %>">%
        <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object2-low" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.lowobjectives3 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object2-med" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.medobjectives3 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object2-high" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.highobjectives3 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object2" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.highobjectives3 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object2" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.highobjectives3 %>">
        <input class="inputbudget procentages international-object2" id="procentages"   onkeydown="return false"  value="<%= international.highobjectives3 %>">
      <br>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

**INPUT 3**

```
  <div class="colum" id="regio">
    <p>Low</p>
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-0" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-1" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-2" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-9" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
  </div>
  <!-- COLUM 2 MEDIUM -->
  <div class="colum" id="regio">
    <p>Medium</p>
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-3" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-4" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-5" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-10" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
  </div>
  <!-- COLUM 3 HIGH -->
  <div class="colum" id="regio">
    <p>High</p>
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-6" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-7" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-8" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
    <input class="box" value="1" id="value3-11" type="text" onkeydown="return false" />
  </div>
```

**CODE**

```
    // procentages

      //domestic-1

      $(".domestic-object-procentages-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-procentages-low-1-" + (i + 1));
      });

      $(".domestic-object-procentages-med").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-procentages-med-1-" + (i + 1));
      });

      $(".domestic-object-procentages-high").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-procentages-high-1-" + (i + 1));
      });

      //

      //continental-1

          $(".continental-object-procentages-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-procentages-low-2-" + (i + 1));
      });

          $(".continental-object-procentages-med").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-procentages-med-2-" + (i + 1));
      });

          $(".continental-object-procentages-high").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-procentages-high-2-" + (i + 1));
      });

      //

      //International-1

          $(".international-object-procentages-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-procentages-low-3-" + (i + 1));
      });

          $(".international-object-procentages-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-procentages-med-3-" + (i + 1));
      });

          $(".international-object-procentages-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-procentages-high-3-" + (i + 1));
      }); 

      //

      //domestic-2

          $(".domestic-object-procentages-2-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-procentages-low-1-2-" + (i + 1));
      });

          $(".domestic-object-procentages-2-med").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-procentages-med-1-2-" + (i + 1));
      });

          $(".domestic-object-procentages-2-high").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-procentages-high-1-2-" + (i + 1));
      });

      //

      //continental-2

          $(".continental-object-procentages-2-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-procentages-low-2-2-" + (i + 1));
      });
          $(".continental-object-procentages-2-med").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-procentages-med-2-2-" + (i + 1));
      }); 
          $(".continental-object-procentages-2-high").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-procentages-high-2-2-" + (i + 1));
      });


      //

      //International-2

          $(".international-object-procentages-2-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-procentages-low-3-2-" + (i + 1));
      });
          $(".international-object-procentages-2-med").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-procentages-med-3-2-" + (i + 1));
      });
          $(".international-object-procentages-2-high").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-procentages-high-3-2-" + (i + 1));
      });

      //

    //

    //objects

      //domestic-1

      $(".domestic-object-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-low-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".domestic-object-med").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-med-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".domestic-object-high").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-high-" + (i + 1));
      });

      //

      //continental-1
      $(".continental-object-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-low-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".continental-object-med").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-med-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".continental-object-high").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-high-" + (i + 1));
      });
      //

      //international-1

      $(".international-object-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-low-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".international-object-med").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-med-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".international-object-high").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-high-" + (i + 1));
      });

      //

      //domestic-2

      $(".domestic-object2-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-2-low-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".domestic-object2-med").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-2-med-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".domestic-object2-high").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "domestic-input-2-high-" + (i + 1));
      });

      //continental-2

      $(".continental-object2-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-2-low-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".continental-object2-med").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-2-med-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".continental-object2-high").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "continental-input-2-high-" + (i + 1));
      });

      //

      //international-2

      $(".international-object2-low").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-2-low-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".international-object2-med").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-2-med-" + (i + 1));
      });
      $(".international-object2-high").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "international-input-2-high-" + (i + 1));
      });

      //

        var i=0;
  $("#domestic-input-2-low-" + (i + 1)).each(function(i) {
    $(this).val()= $("#value3-0").val()/100 * $("#domestic-input-low-" + (i + 1)).val()
  })

    //
  });




//
```

Comment: This looks overly complex trying to use ID's and would probably be a lot simpler using traverses. Show some sample html as per [mcve]

Comment: isn't... your last snippet missing a `2`? also... `.each.val()`? what is that?

Comment: @charlietfl I've added some of the HTML, will this help you get a better understanding of it?

Comment: @KevinB I'm trying to add it to each value. Not sure what you mean with the missing 2

Comment: yeah, .each there doesn't make sense. that's what .val does alone.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, that's true. Is there a technique to accomplish my objective?

Comment: well, yeah, of course, the question is... Can your existing technique get you there? Probably, if you figured out what was wrong with it. As it stands i don't see what's wrong with it from a logic point of view other than it being overly complex. Performing operations on two values is easy, your problem is with the logic surrounding that. Most likely one of the selectors aren't doing what you expect.

Comment: @KevinB I'll improve my technique and knowledge, but tackling this problem, But i'll look into my selectors

Comment: Really not clear what you are even trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.val() is a function and not a property that you can assign values to it.

See the snippet below doing something similar of what you're trying to achieve:

```js
function updateValues() {
  
  event.preventDefault();
  
  $('.table-row').each(function(i, e) {
    
    var totalField = $(e).find('#total-' + i);
    
    var value1 = $(e).find('#first-' + i).val();
    var value2 = $(e).find('#second-' + i).val();
    
    totalField.val(value1 + value2);
    
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td><input type="text" class="numeric-field" id="total-0" disabled /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="numeric-field" id="first-0" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="numeric-field" id="second-0" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td><input type="text" class="numeric-field" id="total-1" disabled /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="numeric-field" id="first-1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="numeric-field" id="second-1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td><input type="text" class="numeric-field" id="total-2" disabled /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="numeric-field" id="first-2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="numeric-field" id="second-2" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="updateValues()">Update</button>
```

Comment: Check your output-  you are concatenating strings, not adding numbers

Comment: Thank you for your response, 

Your answer is great, but trying to implement it to my code i came across one problem. if you put them all into one div it only calculates the first input fields. 

I'm trying to do all

You can have a look in this pen:
http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/GrYbMK

Comment: nvm, figured it out. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the desired output is but I have tried to simplify the code provided to illustrate how you could do the calculations given the values in the input fields

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  var i = 0;

  // assign ids to the inputs
  $(".infield").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', "infield-" + (i + 1));
  });

  $("#go").on('click', function() {
    // get operand
    var operationToPerform = $("#operator").val();

    // get input fields
    var infield1 = parseInt($("#infield-1").val());
    var infield2 = parseInt($("#infield-2").val());

    // will hold the results of the operation.
    var resultVal;

    switch (operationToPerform) {
      case "+":
        resultVal = infield1 + infield2;
        break;
      case "-":
        resultVal = infield1 - infield2;
        break;
      case "*":
        resultVal = infield1 * infield2;
        break;
      case "/":
        resultVal = infield1 / infield2;
        break;
      default:
        resultVal = "Select an Operand"
    }

    $("#results").text(resultVal).effect("shake", {
      times: 4
    }, 1000).effect('highlight');

  });

});
```

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <input type="text" class="infield" />
  <select id="operator">
    <option value="">Select an Operand</option>
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="*">*</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="infield" />
  <button id="go">Go</button>
  <hr/>Results: <span id="results"></span> 
  <br/>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm looking more for what Daniel created, below your post. even though your answer looks amazing